# Pass HTML id from one page to another and transfer it to textbox when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

edit: i've passed id from one page to another. 
2nd edit: I've also displayed the result of the text i click on popup.

I've created search box which shows results instantly by using **Ajax**. And the results displayed there are username, firstname and lastname. i want to make the clicked text which is username to go to another text box.

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                alert(+$("#tran").text);
                //This displays the text i clicked. which is username here

            });
                });    

    </script>
```

after that i want to transfer that clicked result of username to a text box shown below:

```
<input class="to" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="receiver" id="username" required="required">


How do we do that?
```

Comment: Since you use jQuery, it is best practice to use the jQuery [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) or [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) functions to make Ajax-calls.

Comment: would you mind being more specific? I'm new to jquery. just started using them. Tried doing this but didnt work  $.get("searchuser.php"),ready(function()

Comment: On [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp) are some useful tutorials, maybe it can help you go further.

Comment: If you have access to the ID of a textbox, you can use it any time [via `document.getElementById()`] to change the "`value`" property of the text box.  Somehow I think you are actually asking about something else, though it isn't clear what.  Perhaps you want to replace that `alert()` with something clickable?  One way (among several) is to use a `span` element, and assign it an ID and and on-click event-handler.  You can uses its ID much like the ID of the textbox, but the property you want to set, to display text inside the `span` element, is called "`innerHTML`" instead of "`value`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** Thank you everyone i found this solution myself.

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#div2,a#tran").click (function(event) {
            // a#tran is id of hyperlink which you click located inside #div2

            var _id = $("#tran").text(); // Text that gets sent to box

            $("#username").val(_id);
            // #username is id of text box where you want to send text

            });
                });    

    </script>
```